# AnsiString does not work (AnsiString identifier is not defined)

Tags: c++, converters, c++builder, shellexecute, borland-c++

Here's the code:

```
AnsiString path = "BrowserBot.exe";
ShellExecute(0, TEXT("open"), path.c_str(), TEXT("-parametr"), 0, SW_SHOW);
```

Writes an error that the AnsiString identifier is not defined. I don't know what the problem is.

All connected libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: `AnsiString` is a Borland/Embarcadero C++Builder specific class. Do you have the right environment, the right tools, and the right `#include` header files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AnsiString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString) is a string class that is specific to the C++Builder compiler.  If you are using that compiler, make sure you are compiling your project with C++Builder's VCL (Visual Component Library) or FMX (FireMonkey) framework enabled, and that you have a corresponding `#include <vcl.h>` or `#include <fmx.h>` statement in your C++ code.

Otherwise, if you are using any other compiler, you should use the standard C++ `std::string` class instead (which can also be used in C++Builder), eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string path = "BrowserBot.exe";
ShellExecuteA(0, "open", path.c_str(), "-parametr", 0, SW_SHOW);
```